# Serial Port Connection, Readline/ReadExisting Does Not Work

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to make a serial connection to another machine. I'm using a Virtual Serial Port Emulator to try this. The settings that I use on hyperterminal are like the ones below. I can see the portopen is `true`, but I can't check whether I can write or read.  When I try the `ReadLine` method it gives `TimeoutException` and when it's readExisting command it does nothing. `DataReceived` is never triggered too. Can you help me out with that ?

```
 private void Page1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        //Port name can be identified by checking the ports


        // section in Device Manager after connecting your device
        serialPort1.PortName = "COM14"; // that one works for me

        //Provide the name of port to which device is connected

        //default values of hardware[check with device specification document]
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 115200;
        serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
        serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
        serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 8;
        serialPort1.ReadTimeout = 2000;
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);  //
        // Writes data to the Serial Port output buffer 

        //opens the port
        serialPort1.Open();
    }

      private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {


        inputData = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { DoUpdate(); });


    }

     public void DoUpdate()
    {
        textOutput.Text = (textOutput.Text + inputData);

    }

     private void btnReadExist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((serialPort1.IsOpen == true))
        {


           serialPort1.WriteLine("something"); 
           string read= serialPort1.ReadExisting();
           //string output = serialPort1.ReadLine();
           textOutput.Text += read;

        }
    }


    private void Page1_FormClosed(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //  Close the Serial Port
          serialPort1.Close();
    }
```

Comment: When you say **COM14** "works for me" what do you mean? Do you mean it just connects successfully or do you **KNOW** that is the port the simulator is running on? You could be connecting to something else and not the simulator?

Comment: While using the emulator I've used other ports and it connected successfully. What I mean is , while connecting to the actual device, the connection is successful when I use COM14.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're reading in two code blocks: first, directly after sending the text in the button's event. Secondly you have an event assigned that reads data when called asynchronously. You should decide which one to use and remove the other.

Comment: It doesn't work when I remove the DataReceived event neither. I've used writeline(also write method later)and readexisting . Can I see the text I've written onto SerialConnection ?